# Is there anyway to remove the first aid shortcut button?

Tags: resident-evil-7

If I have a First Aid Med in my inventory, pressing the <kbd>R1</kbd> button will automatically use one of them, without having to manually select it from the inventory menu.

While I accept this would be useful in a pinch, I am finding it more a hindrance as I keep accidentally using them when I don't need to.

Is there anyway to disable this feature, or even assign another item to that button?

Comment: Is the question limited to PS4?

Comment: @user598527: I doubt it. I expect it's probably RB for XBOX, but can't say for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem early on. There's no way to do this via in-game menus, but you could [use the PS4's accessibility features](https://www.google.com/amp/www.howtogeek.com/245977/how-to-remap-buttons-on-your-playstation-4s-controller/amp/) to reassign the R1 button to another button, like L2. That would prevent you from wasting healing items.

Comment: At this stage it would be worse to change it around, I am mostly used to avoiding pressing it now I am more familiar with the game. Surprised they don't let you change it in game though